# SQL: Select unique column based on priority (hierarchy) and availability of other columns

Tags: sql, select, conditional-statements, hierarchy

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer version 4.0.3.16
I have a table like this:

```
Name   | Value  | Sequence
------ | ------ | ------
A      | 12     | 0
A      | 15     | 1
A      | 11     | 2
B      | null   | 0
B      | 5      | 2
B      | 7      | 3
C      | 12     | 1
```

I want to select the rows in each name category with smallest sequence number and not null Value. Aka result would be

```
Name   | Value  | Sequence
------ | ------ | ------
A      | 12     | 0
B      | 5      | 2
C      | 12     | 1
```

If there are no available value for the name, then show value as null with smallest sequence number.

Comment: What rdbms are you working with? product and version please.

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer version 4.0.3.16

Answer (score 1):

If your db support tuple You could use a tuple and a in clause with a subselect

```
  select * from 
  my_table  
  where ( name, sequnce ) in ( 
      select Name, min(sequence) 
      from my_table 
      group by name 
      where value is not null)
  where Value is not null
```

or for others DB a join

```
  select a.* from 
  my_table  a
  INNER join ( 
      select Name, min(sequence)  as  min_seq
      from my_table 
      group by name 
      where value is not null) t on  a.name = t.name 
                          and a.sequence = t.min_seq 
                           and a.name is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand, you need this:

```
with the_table(Name , Value , Sequence) as(
select 'A',12     , 0 from dual union all
select 'A',15     , 1 from dual union all
select 'A',11     , 2 from dual union all
select 'B',null   , 0 from dual union all
select 'B',5      , 2 from dual union all
select 'B',7      , 3 from dual union all 
select 'C',12     , 1  from dual
)

-- below is actual query:

select the_table.* from the_table
inner join (
    select Name, min(case when Value is not null then Sequence end) as mn, max(Sequence) as mx 
    from the_table
    group by Name
) t
on the_table.Name = t.Name and the_table.Sequence = coalesce(t.mn, t.mx)
```

Get rows with smallest `Sequence` for every `Name`, where `Value` is not null. If all `Value`s are null's for name, then get rows with highest `Sequence` for that name.